# Simultaneous Fetches with a Paginated Backbone Collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have a paginated collection that could be simultaneously making multiple fetch()es.  E.G. a user could click on 'page 1' see  a 'Loading...' message then click on 'page 2' before page 1 loads, which would fire off another fetch() request (sending down a different page param obviously).  Hopefully that makes sense.  I handle this within a View (Coffeescript):

```
render: ->
  if @collection.hasPage()
    # render the view
  else
    el.append '<h3>Loading...</h3>'

    @collection.fetch
      success: (coll, resp) => @render()
```

However, if I click on page 1, then page 2 before page 1 loads, the success callback for page 1 ends up being called twice (so three success() calls overall).  The success() callbacks get called in this order: page 1, page 2, page 1

Why is this happening?  Should I be handling this with events?  Should I not allow multiple fetch()es simultaneously?  Thanks for the help.

**UPDATE**

This is how I'm doing it now:

```
initialize: ->
  @page = @collection.page

render: ->
  if @collection.hasPage(@page)
    #render
  else
    el.append 'Loading...'

    @collection.fetch
       success: (coll,resp) =>
         # do some stuff with coll
         if @page == @collection.page
           @render()
```

Seems to work...

Comment: Expecting `Page1,Page2` but end up getting `Page1,Page2,Page1`? It is better you subscribe to reset event of the collection. ReRender the collection with the view. Do not pass options to fetch method.

Comment: @Deeptechtons Yeah exactly.  Shall subscribe to reset, thank you.  Also just curious as to why it's happening.  Why no options to fetch (also passing url)?

Comment: I still don't know. Being involved in developing Backbone apps for several months now, at certain times the library springs surprises out of nowhere. I will try to replicate your situation with a jsfiddle and **will get back only if i can reproduce**

Comment: @Deeptechtons How would you handle delayed AJAX requests with jsFiddle?

Comment: pass `{wait:true}` as options to requests that make ajax request. ex: save,delete,create. so if creating new student do this `Collection.Create({name:"Murphy",course:"CS1201"},{wait:true,success:fn,error:fn})`; above code will create a new student, add to collection, invoke `sync` event and then `add event`  finally the callback

Comment: @Deeptechtons appreciate your time.  Figured out the issue below.  In short: I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why it happens (at least according to my logic):

1. Render is called -> a fetch for page 1 is fired
2. User clicks page 2
3. Render is called -> a fetch for page 2 is fired
4. The fetch from first call to page 1 returns -> success: (coll, resp) => @render()
5. WHAM BAM Render is called AGAIN -> page hasn't been loaded so...
6. Fetch is called for the 3rd time and for page 1
7. Somewhere around here the call for page 2 returns

And you definitely should handle this with events as the problem is caused by your render function doing the fetching and the drawing.

Comment: Why didn't I check the network tab?  Three requests are being made.  When the request comes back, @collection.page is now 2, which hasn't been loaded, so it goes through to fetch() again...  I think I need to attach the page to the view and pass that to hasPage() (parse() pushes the fetched page # onto an array attached to the coll)  Or something -- will figure it tomorrow.  Thanks!